# Error converting json to csv file python

Tags: python

The other solutions exisiting are not working for me. I want to compare a csv file to a json file to see if the json file as has any strings that are in the csv file.

I've tried (adapted from other stackoverflow post)

```
jsoned = json.loads(x)

with open("test.csv", "wb+") as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for i in jsoned:
        csv_writer.writerow([i[u'tag'],
                             i[u'newtag']])
```

But it's not working. Would I better to go the other route and turn the csv to a json?

**edit**

Json file:

```
{"tag":["security architecture","systems security engineering","architecture","program protection planning (ppp)","system security engineering","security engineering"],"newtag":["security","architecture engineering & policy","certified ethical hacker","security policy and risk management","sse","enterprise transition plan","plan","tax","capacity analysis"]}
```

csv:

```
id  tag
88  systems engineering
88  project management
88  program management
88  strategic planning
88  requirements analysis
88  acquisition
88  enterprise architecture
134 java
134 software engineering
134 software development
134 xml
134 c++
134 sql
134 web services
134 javascript
134 linux
134 html
134 python
134 c
134 c#
134 software architecture
134 eclipse
134 jquery
134 oracle
134 perl
161 project management
161 systems engineering
161 requirements engineering
161 requirements management
```

I want to see which id the json file has the most matches with (so I want to know how many tag matches per id), but I'm not sure how to deal with comparing a json to a csv

Comment: Define "it's not working"

Comment: any chance we could see the format of the json and csv files?

Comment: There is no comparison taking place, you're just writing to the file. What exactly should be compared?

Comment: have added the json and csv. i have written python code to compare if it was two csv's. But I have multiple json files that I want to be able to run. So manually making csv files is inefficient

Comment: How does your code snippet relates to your question exactly ???

Comment: So the problem is given a csv file of id's and tags and given a json file with tags. Which id should the json file be? but I don't know how to import json into python to find the matches with the csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have misunderstood your question, but hopefully this will at least get you started.

I'm SURE there must be a better way of doing this, but here is a way of doing it.

First, load your data, get your csv data into a nested list, get your json data into a dict. Then get all the unique IDs in the csv file.

Go through the csv file for each unique ID and count the number of tags present in the json tags.

If the count is greater than the current maximum, then store that ID as the best one.

After the loop is complete, you should have the ID which has the most tags present in the json tags.

```
# load csv data
with open("csvdata.csv") as csvFile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
    loadedCSV = [row for row in reader]

# load json data and get list of tags
jsonTags = json.load("jsonFile.json")["tags"]

# create a unique list of ids from csv file
uniqueIDs = list(set([row[0] for row in loadedCSV]]))

# best match so far
selectedID = None

# keep track of best count
maxCount = 0

# go through ids
for id in uniqueIDs:

    # count for specific ID
    idCount = 0

    # go through tags in csv and add one to count if in json tags
    for row in loadedCSV:
        if row[0] == id:
            if row[1] in jsonTags:
                idCount += 1
    # compare count to current max
    if idCount > maxCount:
        selectedID = id
```

Comment: Thanks RichSmith, I will look into that. I have something similar to that code, but was struggling with the json.

Comment: when I print the selectedID or the maxCount though nothing appears. It seems to break after idCount =+1. is it because it is comparing to the id and not the tag in the csv?

Comment: @karmesto it might be worth printing out the uniqueIDs, loadedCSV and jsonTags before the loop just to make sure they're in the correct format and were loaded properly, I'll check over the rest of the code in the morning :)